# How to run my ruby on rails web app using command prompt (not IDE)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line

I'm using Aptana as IDE to develop a small application. To test the application, I use the command prompt of Aptana.

Im using a laptop that has **command prompt with ruby and rails** but not aptana. All I see is a **C:Sites>**. The application I'm trying to access is located in a different folder.

What should I do the run the ruby on rails application from the prompt?

Thanks for helping

Comment: "How to lunch"?  Great, now I'm hungry.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, still fun? Lol! English is not my first language. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Other resources to check out http://rubyinstaller.org/ and http://railsinstaller.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:  `cd` to your project folder, then `rails s` or `script/server`.
Access it from `localhost:3000` from your browser.

Comment: if you are running on rails3 its rails s, if you are running rails < 3 its ruby script/server

Answer (score 2):

Can't help you to locate the directory of your Rails application but when you do, just

```
rails server
```

If that doesn't work then try following [this](http://accidentaltechnologist.com/ruby-on-rails/running-rails-3-on-windows/).

Answer (score 1):

**In Environment mode**

- rails s OR rails server OR rails s -e development

**In Production mode**

- rails s -e production (do not forget to pre-compile your assets before running)

if your platform is **jruby** then add `jruby` i.e. `jruby -S rails s -e development` at the front of the rails command.